# "ERROR: query has no destination for result data" when returning SETOF

Tags: postgresql

I'm having problems with this function:

> The error I get is ERROR:  query has no destination for result data.

What am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION list_top_Patients_Visit()
RETURNS SETOF PatientsList AS $$

DECLARE
_Pat_Number visit.Pat_Number%type;
_Patient_Name patient.NAme%type; 
_Doc_Number doctor.Doc_Number%type;
_Doc_Name doctor.Name%type;
_Specialty doctor.Specialty%type;
_Total_visit INTEGER;
_Total_price visit.Price%type;
_Max_price visit.Price%type;

BEGIN

FOR _Pat_Number, _Total_visit IN (

SELECT v.pat_number  _Pat_Number, count((v.pat_number))  _Total_visit

FROM visit v, patient p
    GROUP BY v.pat_number, p.Name
    ORDER BY _Total_visit DESC, v.pat_number
    LIMIT 5) 
    LOOP
        SELECT count((visit.pat_number))  _Total_visit, patient.Name  _Patient_Name, visit.doc_number  _Doc_Number, count((visit.doc_number))  max_metge, sum(visit.price)  _Total_price, max(visit.price)  _Max_price,  doctor.name  _Doc_Name, doctor.specialty  _Specialty
        FROM visit, doctor, patient
        WHERE visit.pat_number=_Pat_Number and visit.doc_number=doctor.doc_number and patient.pat_number=_Pat_Number
        GROUP BY visit.doc_number, doctor.name, specialty, patient.Name
        ORDER BY max_metge DESC, visit.doc_number
        LIMIT 1;
        RETURN NEXT  _Patient_Name, _Doc_Name, _Specialty, _Total_visit, _Total_price, _Max_price;
    END LOOP;

END;
$$LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `SELECT ... INTO ...` to set variables in PL/PgSQL from a query.

`SELECT` without `INTO` is not permitted. If you want to discard the result, use `PERFORM` instead. If you wish to store the result in variables, use `SELECT ... INTO ...`. See the manual for details.

In this case you can use `RETURN NEXT QUERY SELECT ...` instead of separate `SELECT` and `RETURN` steps.